# How to use dlib for object detection in Python?

Tags: python, svm, object-detection, dlib

i have a task that i need to detect objects that relates to only one class, let's say "A". i need to use svm from dlib. so here i will need both feature extractor and detector "svm". i can use hog and svm.

i'm not familiar yet with the whole process. can you help me with a python code to solve this problem using fhog and svm from dlib?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)